# how delete account YouTube for deceased personal

Tags: gmail

**my relative is pass away and I want to delete his account youtube but I don't know his email and password.**

Answer (score -1):

You can go to [Google’s support page](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/6357590?hl=en), which can be found from a simple search into Google. This will take you to a page in which you will submit information in regards to the deceased person.